# What is the equivalent listview.setSelection in case of Recycler View

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

In the case of a `ListView` if we want to make a particular item selected we use the `setSelection` method. How do we do this in case of `RecyclerView`?

Comment: go to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html and ^F position

Answer (score 29):

Use `RecyclerView` `LayoutManager` to scroll item at position

`recyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(position)`

Answer (score 22):

Check

```
scrollToPositionWithOffset(int position, int offset)
scrollToPositionWithOffset(5,0);
```

from LinearLayoutManager 
Scroll to the specified adapter position with the given offset from resolved layout start.

pass offset as 0 if you want selection at top

This worked for me

Comment: Worked for me! I had to cast my layout manager to LinearLayoutManager first. Thanks         ((LinearLayoutManager)getLayoutManager()).scrollToPositionWithOffset(5, 0);

Answer (score 7):

Check

```
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(cursor.getcount() - 1);
```

Answer (score 4):

ListView.setSelected() does (at least) two things:

1. It sets the item in the list to be selected (while removing the selection from another item - if such exists)
2. It scrolls the list so that the item will be visible on the screen.

To achieve 2. either call scrollToPosition() method of RecyclerView (as indicated by Loser), or call one of the scrolling methods of the LayoutManager object depending on your desired scrolling behavior.

For example,
recyclerView.getLayoutManager().smoothScrollToPosition()

You may want to scroll the minimum so that the selected item shows on the screen.
If so and you are using LinearLayoutManager or GridLayoutManager, you can build such scroll logic based on 
findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() and findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() defined in these classes.

Achieving 1. is more tricky. You may want to use the following recipe:

First define a background color in colors.xml, **item_state_selected_color**, to be used when an item is selected.
In your onCreateViewHolder() implementation create a StateListDrawalbe and set it as the background of the view.
Say something like this:

```
public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

    // inflate the item view
    View itemView =  LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).
                           inflate(itemResourceId,viewGroup, false);

    // create color drawable by a resorce id
    ColorDrawable colorDrawableSelected =
       new ColorDrawable(resources.getColor(R.color.item_state_selected_color)); 

   // create StateListDrawable object and define its states
   StateListDrawable stateListDrawable = new StateListDrawable();
   stateListDrawable.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_selected}, colorDrawableSelected);
   stateListDrawable.addState(StateSet.WILD_CARD, null);

   // set the StateListDrawable as background of the item view
   if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
      itemView.setBackgroundDrawable(stateListDrawable); 
   }
   else {
      itemView.itemView.setBackground(stateListDrawable);
   }

   // create view holder object providing it with the item view
   return new YourViewHolder(itemView);   
}
```

In YourAdapter object (or elsewhere) save a variable, mCurrentSelectedPosition (probably initialized to -1) that holds the current selected position.
Still in the adapter, define handler for clicks on recycler view items, depending on your click logic. For example:

```
void onItemClick(int position) {

   YourViewHolder yourViewHolder;

   int oldSelectedPosition = mCurrentSelectedPosition;

   if (position != mCurrentSelectedPosition) {
      mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;

      if (oldSelectedPosition != -1) {
         yourViewHolder = findViewHolderForPosition(oldSelectedPosition); 
         yourViewHolder.itemView.setSelected(false);     
      } 

      yourViewHolder = findViewHolderForPosition(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
      yourViewHolder.itemView.setSelected(true);
   }        
}
```

Next, in the constructor of YourViewHolder set listener to clicks on the item:

```
public YourViewHolder(View itemView,YourAdapter adapter) { 
  mAdapter = adapter;

  // ... other code here ...

  itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Still in YourViewHolder override the onClick() method to delegate handling to the adapter. like this

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   mAdapter.onItemClick(getPosition());
}
```

Now there is just last problem to solve - we need to keep track of the selected item with respect to recycling.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(YourViewHolder yourViewHolder, int position) {

  if (position == mCurrentSelectedPosition) {
     yourViewHolder.itemView.setSelected(true);
  }
  else { 
     yourViewHolder.itemView.setSelected(false);
  }     

  // ... other code here ...  
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: What I don't seem to get about #2 is *when* to call scrollToPosition? if the selection listener is on the individual views, how will the RecyclerView object (which has acces to its layout manager that can call scrolToPosition) be notified that an item is selected?

Comment: @Nonos - You should call scrollToPosition() whenever you want the recycler view to scroll to a specific item (that is not currently showing) by its position.
Further, there is no point in calling scrollToPosition() to scroll to an item being clicked because the fact that the user clicked on it indicates that it's visible and scrolling to its position will therefore have no effect.

Comment: This is true in general, I'm trying to create a custom horizontal layout manager though that will, not only ensure the selected item is visible, but will align the left side of the item with the left side of the recycler view so that the selected item is always on the furthest left.

Comment: @Nonos - Instead of creating a custom layout manager, why don't you use LinearLayoutManager and call setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL) on it. Then catch the click on the item like I explained in my answer. Now you can figure out the location of the view by using findViewHolderForAdapterPosition() on the recycler view and finally do the math and scroll via scrollHorizontallyBy() on the layout manager.

Comment: I know this is a long time after you posted this, but maybe you can still help me out.  I followed this guide and it worked great, except I have one problem:  if mCurrentSelectedPosition is off screen when you select a new item, it crashes with a NPE at the yourViewHolder.itemView.setSelected(false) line in adapter OnItemClick method.  Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: It's hard to tell what the problem may be. Perhaps post a dedicated question for your issue and include the relevant code together with the crash stack trace.