# RecyclerView item selector crashing when current selected item is off screen

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

For an assignment, I had to make a recyclerview with some pre-defined items, and clicking on each of them does some stuff in another view.  That all worked fine, and was probably good enough for my assignment, but I wasn't quite happy with it because there was nothing showing what item was selected, etc.

So I wanted to make a background highlight on the list item whenever it was selected.  After a bit of searching, I found this answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28617619/2437682

I followed the answer, and got results that I was pretty happy with until I noticed that if the currently selected item was off-screen when a new item clicked, it would cause the app to crash with a NPE.

The particular code causing this crash is:

```
void onItemClick(int position) {

        ListItemViewHolder yourViewHolder;

        int oldSelectedPosition = mSelectedIndex;

        if (position != mSelectedIndex) {
            mSelectedIndex = position;


            yourViewHolder = (ListItemViewHolder) recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(oldSelectedPosition);

            //this is the line that causes the crash when the view is off-screen
            yourViewHolder.itemView.setSelected(false);


            yourViewHolder = (ListItemViewHolder) recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(mSelectedIndex);
            yourViewHolder.itemView.setSelected(true);
        }
    }
```

I understand what's happening.  the findViewHolderForAdapterPosition method is returning null if the item is off screen, so I can't change the setSelected property.

What I'm not sure of is how to work around it.  I tried just saying:

```
if (yourViewHolder != null) {
    yourViewHolder.itemView.setSelected(false);
}
```

And that at least keeps the app from crashing, but the next time that list item scrolls back onto the screen, it is still highlighted like it is selected.

Any ideas?

**Update**

Here's the updated adapter and viewholder classes:

```
public class ColorsAdaptor extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListItemViewHolder>{

    @Override
    public ListItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        Context context = viewGroup.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        View listItemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, viewGroup, false);

        ColorDrawable colorDrawableSelected =
                new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.selected));

        StateListDrawable stateListDrawable = new StateListDrawable();
        stateListDrawable.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_selected}, colorDrawableSelected);
        stateListDrawable.addState(StateSet.WILD_CARD, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.border));

        listItemView.setBackgroundDrawable(stateListDrawable);

        ListItemViewHolder viewHolder = new ListItemViewHolder(listItemView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ListItemViewHolder listItemViewHolder, int position) {
        listItemViewHolder.updateView();

        MyColor color = items.get(position);

        TextView colorText = listItemViewHolder.getColorText();
        colorText.setText(color.getName());

        ImageView colorBlock = listItemViewHolder.getColorBlock();
        colorBlock.setBackgroundColor(color.getColorID());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }
}

public class ListItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private TextView colorText;
    private ImageView colorBlock;
    private View itemView;

    public ListItemViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        itemView = view;
        this.colorBlock = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.colorBlock);
        this.colorText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.colorText);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();

                if (position != mSelectedIndex) {

                   ListItemViewHolder oldViewHolder = (ListItemViewHolder) recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(mSelectedIndex);
                   if (oldViewHolder != null) {
                       oldViewHolder.itemView.setSelected(false);
                   }

                    itemView.setSelected(true);
                    mSelectedIndex = position;
                }



                ImageView temp = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.colorBlock);
                colorViewer.setBackground(temp.getBackground());
            }
        });
    }

    public void updateView(){
        Log.d("", "updateView SelectedIndex: " + mSelectedIndex + " adapterPosition: " + getAdapterPosition());
        this.itemView.setSelected(getAdapterPosition() == mSelectedIndex);
    }

    public TextView getColorText() {
        return colorText;
    }

    public ImageView getColorBlock() {
        return colorBlock;
    }

}
```

Oh, and the debug output from the updateView() method.

On first run:

```
SelectedIndex: 0 adapterPosition: 0
SelectedIndex: 0 adapterPosition: 1
SelectedIndex: 0 adapterPosition: 2
SelectedIndex: 0 adapterPosition: 3
SelectedIndex: 0 adapterPosition: 4
SelectedIndex: 0 adapterPosition: 5
SelectedIndex: 0 adapterPosition: 6
```

Then as I scroll up and down a few times and updateView gets called when new views are brought back onto the screen:

```
SelectedIndex: 0 adapterPosition: 7
SelectedIndex: 0 adapterPosition: 9
SelectedIndex: 0 adapterPosition: 2
SelectedIndex: 0 adapterPosition: 0
SelectedIndex: 0 adapterPosition: 7
SelectedIndex: 0 adapterPosition: 9
SelectedIndex: 0 adapterPosition: 2
SelectedIndex: 0 adapterPosition: 0
SelectedIndex: 0 adapterPosition: 7
SelectedIndex: 0 adapterPosition: 9
```

See how it's skipping adapterPositions when scrolling?  So if adapterPosition 8 never comes back up during scrolling, then the view at adapterPosition8 never gets turned off in the updateView() method.

Comment: Have you adapted the `onBindViewHolder()` of the adapter accordingly to set the selection status of itemViews?

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep the item state in the "onBindViewHolder" method.
Also, you should manage the onItemClick inside the view holder, since being there, you're exactly where you want to be, so basically you would have:

YourAdapter.java

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(YourViewHolder yourViewHolder, int i) {
    yourViewHolder.updateView();
}
```

YourViewHolder.java

```
class YourViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{ 
    View itemView;
    public YourViewHolder(View itemView){
        this.itemView = itemView;
    }

    public void updateView(){
        //Do whatever you need to do regarding the item view
        this.itemView.setSelected(getAdapterPosition() == mSelectedIndex);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        if (position == mSelectedIndex){
            //It's the same view, deselect it or just leave it as it is
        } else {
           this.itemView.setSelected(true);
           mSelectedIndex = position;
        }
    }
}
```

Have in mind that you shouldn't put the mSelectedIndex inside the ViewHolder but in a separate class.

Comment: Okay, I did what you said and it sort of works, but there's another weird issue.  So, in that updateView() method, i put a debug log that prints out getAdapterPosition() and mSelectedIndex.  So, when I scroll and new views get recycled, the adapterPosition changes.  Except it seems to change by 2 positions per scroll instead of 1. IE, if getAdapterPosition() prints out a 2, then the next scroll up, it prints out 0. Which means that my odd numbered adapter positions never get run through updateView() and get deselected.  Any ideas?

Comment: Could you update your post with your new implementation so I can check?

Comment: You should implement the View.OnClickListener as I did in the viewholder and manage there all the click stuff. Also use the updateView method to update anything else regarding your view and the constructor just for binding the views.

Comment: I'm not sure how implementing OnClickListener is any different from having an anonymous inner class, but okay, I did it your way.  I'm still confused what you mean, though.  Getting the view I clicked on is fine, it's getting the OTHER view that was already selected but has scrolled off of the screen that is giving me trouble.

Comment: And what if you use getLayoutPosition(), what's the output for that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89915/discussion-between-daniel-ocampo-and-keirathi).