# Android RecyclerView: not getting the focus when calling setSelection(position)

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, focus, selection

I use a recyclerview in an activity, and when the activity opens I call setSelection(position) to scroll to a specific position, but the row in the recyclerview doesn't get the focus. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: I think that method is for [ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27377830/what-is-the-equivalent-listview-setselection-in-case-of-recycler-view)

Comment: I actually figured that out, just call requestFocus on the view.